# passing arguments to the function

Tags: c, parameter-passing

The output of the following ode segment is 9. I think the argument a of the function foo is passed by value. Is my assumption correct. If so, how the output become 9?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

void foo(int[][3]);

int main(void)
{
   int a[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };

   foo(a);
   printf("%d\n", a[2][1]);

   return 0;
}

void foo(int b[][3])
{
   ++b;
   b[1][1] = 9;
}
```

Comment: In C, arrays are never passed by value -- an argument of type "array of T" is adjusted to "pointer to T".

Comment: I run the code and it gives me 8! [**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/j4LuMJ#li_j4LuMJ)

Comment: Wow, lots of wrong answers.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in ways that take answers out of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` syntax for a function parameter's type is just syntactic sugar.  A pointer is passed in this case, just like with any other use of an array in a function call context.  That means your `foo()` function's signature is equivalent to:

```
void foo(int (*b)[3])
```

That is, it accepts a pointer to an array of three integers.  With that in mind, let's look at what your implementation does.  First, `++b` advances the pointer to point to the *next* array of 3 integers in memory.  That is, it advances `b` by `3 * sizeof(int)`.  In the case of your program, that means it's pointing at the "middle row" of `a` - the `{ 4, 5, 6 }` row.

Next, you access element `[2][1]` of the new `b`.  That is, row two, element one of this new offset logical array. That causes your program to write to an address past the end of `a`, which is undefined behaviour.  At this stage, all bets are off.  The output of your program could be *anything*.

You can get back to defined behaviour by changing that line to:

```
b[1][2] = 157;
```

for example.  Then, print `a[2][2]` to see the change from the context of your `main()` function.

Comment: how do you know these things?

Comment: Depending on the ABI, nothing might get pushed on the stack.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Can pass array by value in C?

Comment: No, you cannot pass an array by value in C.  You can pull tricks like putting the array in a structure and then passing the structure by value, though.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler won't copy entire array. if its pass by value how about passing an array of 100000 elements. so its passed as **"Pointer"**. The address is passed as a copy i guess. so changing the contents of address 'll change original thing too.

seems like pass by reference by pointer.

Answer (score 0):

According to: 6.2.3.1/3 & 6.7.5.3/7

In the call to foo, the array expression arr isn't an operand of either sizeof or &,  its type is implicitly converted from "array of int" to "pointer to int" according to . Thus, foo will receive a pointer value, rather than an array value.

So when you do:

```
 void foo(int b[][3])
```

it is being implicitly converted to:

```
 void foo((*b)[3])
```

Comment: Not quite.  It gets converted to `int (*b)[3]`.

Comment: Your edit improves things, sort of.  You're missing a type there now.

Answer (score -1):

The output of your program is **8** as expected.Nothing unexpected here.What you are doing in `b[2][1]=9` after incrementing `b` is writing **9** to the location `a[3][1]`.It doesn't affect the output of `a[2][1]` which remains **8** before and after you call `foo()`.

http://ideone.com/eWFxht

You certainly need to recheck your output.

Comment: This answer is the closest to correct, but writing 9 to `a[3][1]` is undefined behaviour.  OP's program could output 9 in that case, though I'm hard pressed to come up for a good explanation why that might happen.